# How to define a target to include multiple libraries stored in a single directory

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

I want to create a module that allows a target to include multiple static libraries stored in the same directory.

The end goal is to allow a target to include `-L<library dir> -l<staticlib-1> -l<staticlib-2> ... -l<staticlib-n>` when linking.

I've tried using `target_link_libraries` like the following, which didn't worked:

```
    add_library(SomeTargetName INTERFACE)
    target_link_libraries(SomeTargetName INTERFACE "-L${SOME_TARGET_LIBRARY_DIR}" )
```

The above snippet causes the following error message:

> INTERFACE_LIBRARY targets may only have whitelisted properties.  The property "LINK_DIRECTORIES" is not allowed.

Does cmake support this kind of usecase? If so, how is it done?

Comment: `-L${SOME_TARGET_LIBRARY_DIR}` is no library. That's an option. `target_link_options`. And no, create a normal library.

Comment: `target_link_options` was only made available since cmake v3.13, thus there must be a way to do this with without using it. And obviously yes, `-L<XXX>` is not a library but a option [to add a directory to the search path](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html) which was the reason it was there to begin with and used as an example.